# Moving sum of a certain window in R

Tags: r, sum, rolling-computation

I want to calculate a running sum of the next 5 rows. In this case, on row 1 it will show the sum of numbers from row 2 to row 6. The last 5 rows of the data frame can be filled with NA.

The data looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMC5L.jpg)

And the ideal result would look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhW0K.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: `zoo::rollsum()` is your friend

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: We will trade you - can you give us an example of your data first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please consider to read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and add sample data using dput next time.

```
df <- data.frame(t = c(1,3,5,2,1,3,4,6,7,2,1))

library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df$V2 <- rollsum(lead(df$t), 5, align = "left", fill = NA)
df

   t V2
1  1 14
2  3 15
3  5 16
4  2 21
5  1 22
6  3 20
7  4 NA
8  6 NA
9  7 NA
10 2 NA
11 1 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rollsum from the zoo package.

```
library(zoo)
rollsum(df$column, 5)
```

The second argument is the number of lines to sum, here it is five.